# Set json array in nodejs async

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I am new in nodejs and I want to make a json array by comparing id inside a loop but the MongoDB function does not wait for the loop to complete, so data is not coming out properly. It displays the data before the loop ends, below is the code:

```
router.get('/getallcountrydataup',function(req, res) {
    Country
        .where('isDeleted').equals(false)
        .exec(function(err,cData){
            if (!cData) {
                res.json({'status':0,'message': 'No data found','data':[]});
            } else{    
                async.waterfall([
                    function (done) {
                        var countryalldata = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < cData.length; i++) {
                            var country_s = cData[i];
                            State.where('s_c_id').equals(country_s._id)
                                 .exec(function(err, statedata){
                                     country_s.statecount = statedata.length;
                                     //console.log(country_s._id);
                                     console.log(country_s.statecount);
                            });
                            countryalldata.push(country_s);
                        }
                        done(err, countryalldata);
                        //  console.log(countryalldata);
                    },
                    function (countryalldata, done) {
                        console.log(countryalldata);
                        res.json({
                            'status': 1,
                            'message': 'Data found',
                            'data': countryalldata
                        });
                    }
                ]);
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is output of the `countryalldata` variable printed before the loop will complete. I want to print its output after loop execution is complete.

Comment: Use camelCase instead of underscores: `countyAllData`

Comment: so you never able to do that cause  you can not stop nodejs event loop and it does not wait for query response till you dont set timeout for that one other way is use wait.for mdule that its in npm.js but it will work just for

Comment: standard callback function and not for `.exec` or `.then` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`State.where` is asynchronous so it should be synchronized. For example with `async.map`

```
router.get('/getallcountrydataup',function(req, res) {
    Country
      .where('isDeleted').equals(false)
      .exec(function(err,cData){
        if (!cData) {
            res.json({'status':0,'message': 'No data found','data':[]});
        } else {
          async.waterfall([
            function (done) {
              async.map(cData, function (country_s, done2) {
                // Convert country_s into plain object. It's not a mongoose
                // model anymore
                country_s = country_s.toObject();

                State.where('s_c_id')
                .equals(country_s._id)
                .exec(function(err,statedata){
                    if (err) {
                      done2(err);
                      return;
                    }

                    country_s.statecount = statedata.length;
                    console.log(country_s.statecount);

                    done2(null, country_s)
                });
              }, function(err, countryalldata) {
                if (err) {
                  done(err);
                }
                else {
                  done(null, countryalldata)
                }
              });
            },
            function (countryalldata, done) {
              console.log(countryalldata);
              res.json({'status':1,'message': 'Data found','data':countryalldata});
            }
          ]);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hello pasha rumkin thanks for help but i don't found the statecount column in my json array as we write ' country_s.statecount = statedata.length;' it display in console.log but not display in whole json array.

Comment: i want to include statecount column in my countryalldata variable.

Comment: This is bacause mongoose doesn't allow custom fields for models. So you need to convert models into objects before appending `statecount`: `country_s = country_s.toObject(); country_s.statecount = statedata.length;`

Comment: YOUR ANSWER IS HELPFUL THANKS

Comment: @sunsil You're welcome. And please use nodejs style guide https://github.com/felixge/node-style-guide to make your code clear and simple to read.